# Disable the new ubuntu 18.04 welcome screen

Tags: 18.04

We deploy Ubuntu desktops in our environment at scale and I want to kill the new welcome screen so it doesn't appear on all newly built machines at first log in.

Has anyone figured out how to do this yet?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the solution to this myself so I'm posting it here for all those who might want to know.

The welcome screen is part of the **`gnome-initial-setup`** package. The first time a user logs into a new machine the command `/usr/lib/gnome-initial-setup/gnome-initial-setup --exisiting-user` runs.

for us simply *removing the `gnome-initial-setup` package* during kickstart is a suitable fix as we don't require any of the gnome initial setup stuff anyway (we don't want to create local user accounts or set the system time etc).

if you do still want the pre-login welcome stuff then you'll need a different solution.

Comment: In this initial setup, user opt in or out sending reports to Ubuntu for example. Did you notice any side effects after removing the gnome-initial-setup package ? Did you removed the ubuntu-report package too ?

Answer (score 9):

I am in the same boat as Dean and found this article + another ones.

[Here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1067653#c7) Rui Matos recommends to append `InitialSetupEnable=false` in `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` (in Ubuntu `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`).

So edit `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and add the following:

```
[daemon]
InitialSetupEnable=false
```

Hope this helps someone else to get rid of the Welcome Screen.

Comment: This seems reasonable, but to me it did not work at all. Ubuntu 18.04.2. sokunrotanak's solution worked tho.

Answer (score 7):

As a side note, you can cleanly create the necessary files to *cancel* the action.

On my end, I'm installing packages on an embedded system and for that I create one user. I want to avoid the "initial setup wizard" and all I have to do is create one file in the user's `.config` directory:

```
touch /home/${NEW_USER}/.config/gnome-initial-setup-done
```

So I can place that command line in my `package.postinst` file and that user will never see the initial setup wizard.

---

How does that work?

If you know the names (which other users mentioned) of the startup files and you look into them, the files include a condition:

```
AutostartCondition=unless-exists gnome-initial-setup-done
```

So if you create that file, it won't start. There are several types of conditions, the tour one is the opposite:

```
AutostartCondition=if-exists run-welcome-tour
```

So you need to create that file for the welcome tour to kick in and once done with the tour, the file gets deleted. Maybe they save the step you're on in that file. So in our script we could add the following to make sure the welcome tour doesn't start:

```
rm -f /home/${NEW_USER}/.config/run-welcome-tour
```

This solution is much cleaner than any others (except for uninstalling the *offending* packages if that's an option for you).

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to uninstall the package, you can edit the file

```
sudo vi /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-initial-setup-first-login.desktop
```

by adding a "#" (without quotes) to the beginning of the execute line like this:

```
#Exec=/usr/lib/gnome-initial-setup/gnome-initial-setup --existing-user
```

Comment: This did work for me on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: a oneliner command to do this is `sudo sed -ri 's/^(Exec=.*)$/#\1/' /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-initial-setup-first-login.desktop
`

Answer (score 2):

I also achieved this by adding the file /etc/skel/.config/gnome-initial-setup-done

```
sudo touch /etc/skel/.config/gnome-initial-setup-done
```

Answer (score 1):

Following @sokunrotanak-srey's route, I'd rather use `dpkg-divert` like so:

**First**, replace the `Exec=...` line with `Exec=/bin/true` in all the `.desktop` files to to make them dummy

**Second**, use dpkg-divert to keep local changes even if the package has a newer version of the `.desktop` files:

```
# dpkg-divert --local --add /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-initial-setup-copy-worker.desktop
Adding 'local diversion of /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-initial-setup-copy-worker.desktop to /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-initial-setup-copy-worker.desktop.distrib'

# dpkg-divert --local --add /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-initial-setup-first-login.desktop
Adding 'local diversion of /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-initial-setup-first-login.desktop to /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-initial-setup-first-login.desktop.distrib'

# dpkg-divert --local --add /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-welcome-tour.desktop
Adding 'local diversion of /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-welcome-tour.desktop to /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-welcome-tour.desktop.distrib'
```