# How to disable telemetry for all users

Tags: users, 18.04, telemetry

I installed 18.04 (clean install) on a computer that is intended to be a multi-user system. Every new user I create gets asked to opt out of telemetry on his or her first login (as part of the welcome screen, as shown in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1027532/how-to-opt-out-of-system-information-reports)). As an admin, I do not want the system to ever send these reports to Canonical, even if one of the users accidentally misses the question, e.g. by quickly clicking through the welcome screen.

**How can I pre-emptively opt-out of sending system reports for all users?**

I know that I can just log in as each user myself after I create them. However:

1. Is there is a command or setting that can do it once and for all?
2. If possible, I would like the users to still get the welcome screen (since it explains what has changed in 18.04), but with the telemetry question disabled, already set to No, or skipped altogether.

It appears that the welcome screen can be completely removed by [uninstalling the gnome-initial-setup package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028822/disable-the-new-ubuntu-18-04-welcome-screen) but I am unsure if this disables the telemetry.

Comment: This answer might help as it provides method to block all reports https://askubuntu.com/a/1030168/696245