# Disable the Ubuntu 18.04 Welcome Screen with Custom ISO

Tags: server, gnome, login, custom-distributions

How do I disable the Gnome welcome screen on first login?

I'm building a custom ISO for Ubuntu Server 18.04.3 LTS and then adding the ubuntu-desktop package (these builds are for developers who want a workstation version of our server build).

I need to skip the welcome stuff for the GUI. We use LDAP authentication so no local accounts need to be set up.

I've tried all three things mentioned at [Disable the new ubuntu 18.04 welcome screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028822/disable-the-new-ubuntu-18-04-welcome-screen)

- remove the gnome-initial-setup package
- add the "InitialSetupEnable=false" line to /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
- comment the Exec line in /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-initial-setup-first-login.desktop

In all of these cases, the machine reboots to a black screen. The OS is running (I can SSH in) and gnome appears to be running if I run ps aux | grep -i gnome but the console is black and ctrl-alt-f1 (or f2, etc) doesn't switch me to a new console.

If I undo my changes and reboot I go back to the welcome screen.

Any guidance?

I have done some noodling: With the GUI up (Welcome enabled), I can log in via SSH as a regular account with X11 forwarding on the remote machine and run /usr/lib/gnome-initial-setup/gnome-initial-setup --existing-user. Then I can go to the console (at the welcome screen), hit ctrl-alt-f2 and log in as my regular account, and THEN enter startx and I get a desktop.

I did also try completing the welcome dialog. It appears to be running "/usr/lib/gnome-initial-setup/gnome-initial-setup" without the --existing-user flag so it wants to create a new user. I entered info for a throwaway user and it kicked to some console output and hangs at:
[ OK ] Started Hold until boot process finishes up.

It stays there until I reboot and then comes up with a black screen again. And this time I can't get away from the black screen. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling gnome-initial-setup with no luck. Ended up redeploying the build again.

What I need is an unattended way to skip all of this and get a new machine that's waiting for LDAP users to log in.

Comment: Hi, Just for Clarification.. Did you build CustomISO and while customizing you did try all those 3 points you mentioned? Remove, Add, Comment?

Comment: Hi There - I am using a custom ISO that points to a pretty simple preseed file. I've tried each of the three fixes I've found described as well as all three together. I've also just tried deleting the gnome-initial-setup user from /etc/passwd to keep the Welcome session from opening, but that also just boots me to a black screen.

Comment: while you were customizing the ISO.. did you remove the package gnome-initial setup??

Comment: The ISO doesn't actually install gnome or gnome-initial-setup. I'm installing the same CLI-based server build we use elsewhere, then using Chef to add ubuntu-desktop and remove gnome-initial-setup

Comment: found some info at https://seven.centos.org/2013/12/preventing-gnome3s-initial-setup/ related to gnome-initial-setp determining if it's run before. It looks for a file ~/.config/gnome-initial-setup-done that should have the word "yes" in it. And when I boot into the Welcome screen, the machine is logged in as a local user gnome-initial-setup with a home drive of /run/gnome-initial-setup. Tried putting that file there but the /run mount is ephemeral so it disappears on reboot. Tried putting it there after boot and logging out the user but it just loads again.

Comment: but I'm not even getting to the new user, this is still happening with the "gnome-initial-setup" user. BTW, I also tried copying that /run/ directory to / and changing the /etc/passwd entry for the GIS user's home drive. Then placed that flag file and rebooted. Still no change. Also, my regular users don't get their home drives from /etc/skel, we have a file server and mount /home there...

Comment: seems complicated.. lets wait if someone helps..

Comment: agreed. currently I'm back to removing the gnome-initial-setup package and trying to troubleshoot the black screen