# Issue after upgrading from 19.04 to 19.10 : logged in as gnome-initial-setup

Tags: upgrade, 19.04, 19.10

I upgraded from 19.04 to 19.10 through the GUI. After the restart, I'm automatically logged in as "gnome-initial-setup" and I can't do anything. Even the shutdown button doesn't work.

Could anybody help me with this issue ?

Comment: Maybe helpfull https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028822/disable-the-new-ubuntu-18-04-welcome-screen

Comment: It got reported as https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-initial-setup/+bug/1850832 , it would be useful to have a journalctl log from a buggy boot though

Comment: This problem got reported as https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-initial-setup/+bug/1850832.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue here. I manged to figure out a way around it though.

1. In grub go to advanced Ubuntu options. Chose the latest kernel in recovery mode
2. Select root shell
3. apt-get remove gnome-initial-setup
4. reboot

Comment: So this is being caused by having an invalid user account. Running:
sudo chsh USER -s /bin/bash

(Replace USER with your user account name.) Will fix the issue.