# Shutdown PC fails since 19.10 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, shutdown

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.10, upgraded from 19.04, upgraded from 18.04.3.

Since the last upgrade (to 19.10), I cannot to shutdown my PC directly from the Main Menu option, because in the "Close Session" Menu options, the "Shutdown" option is in Gray color (not available to be used).

I just can to use the "Close Session" and/or "Restart" options.

I have to physically disconnect the PC from the main electric power line to get the full shutdown.

Why is this?

How can I work around it?

Comment: Please try https://askubuntu.com/a/1185297/197910 and let us know if it solved your problem/

Comment: Also try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183984/ubuntu-19-10-desktop-shutdown

Comment: Until you figure out how to fix the problem, you don’t need to physically unplug your computer to shut it down. Just open a terminal and type, `sudo shutdown -h now`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this data, PJ Singh!!!

Comment: Believe it or not, the issue was fixed without any personal action! I don't know what to say..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution (even the fact I don't know if this is valid in all cases).

The problem is because the process "packagekitd" is working on "behind the cameras".

So...

1) I opened a Terminal session.

2) I wrote: sudo -i (I had to enter my SuperUser keyword).

3) I wrote: killall packagekitd

4) I end the Terminal session.

Then... Eureka!!!

The problem is fixed and now I can to shutdown the PC with the standard button procedure.

BTW: The "packagekitd" app it seems to be not present in old versions of Ubuntu Studio, I'm not sure.